# Problem with figures in a two-column multicols environment

Tags: tables, floats, positioning, two-column, multicol

In the tex which is attached i use multicols{2} for two column text. Everything works properly until use `\begin{center}` for table (in 589 line) or line 631 for figure. The unwanted space is created (as it is shown in the figure). How can i fix this problem? I don't want to use `twocolumn` option in documentclass.

if i use begin{figure*} or begin{table*} the figure and table span in two column.I want to put table on top of single column.(the begin{figure} and begin{table} don't work in multicol environment like twocolumn)

```
 \begin{center} 
\begin{LTR}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule [.4pt] \toprule [.4pt]
$m_1$       &  \qquad \qquad \qquad $0.5$ \\ 
$m_2$       &    \qquad \qquad \qquad  $0.4$ \\ 
$m_3$       &   \qquad \qquad \qquad  $0.2$ \\ 
$m_4$       &   \qquad \qquad \qquad  $0.1$ \\ 
$I_{c_1}$  &   \qquad \qquad \qquad  $0.15$ \\ 
$I_{c_2}$  &  \qquad \qquad \qquad  $0.1$ \\ 
$I_{c_3}$  & \qquad \qquad  \qquad  $0.02$ \\ 
$I_{c_4}$  &   \qquad \qquad \qquad  $0.05$ \\ 
$M_p$       &  \qquad \qquad \qquad   $10*I _{3\times 3}(kg) $ \\ 
$D_p$       &  \qquad \qquad \qquad   $80*I _{3\times 3}(kg) $ \\ 
$K_p$       &   \qquad \qquad \qquad  $600*I _{3\times 3}(kg) $ \\ 
\bottomrule  [.4pt] \bottomrule  [.4pt]
\end{tabular}
 \end{LTR}
 \captionof {table}{پارامترهای مورد استفاده در شبیه‌سازی}   
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: you have not shown your source at all but you should never put a figure inside `begin{center}` as `center` adds vertical space at that point but the figure may move.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ. Do you use a `figure*` environment or a `figure` environment? Is the `hyperref` package loaded? What happens if you employ a `multicols*` environment rather than a `multicols` environment?

Comment: Thanks. My document calss is:  \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} . If i use table* or figure* commands the figure span in two column and if use figure or table commands the figure is not shown. so i use begin{center} which put the table or figure on top of single column.

Comment: you have used `\begin{center}\centering ` the `\centering` does nothing. you can use center and tabular in that way but that is a non floating environment so the table will appear at that point in the source not automatically at the top of the page. As such you need to move it in the source by hand to ensure that there is enough text to fill the column, or use `\raggedbottom` so the extra space comes at the bottom of the page